# How to encode a value in PKCS7 with Java?

Tags: java, encryption, encoding, pkcs#7

I would like to use PKCS7 encryption to encode a value together with Java and Java Servlet. Is there any available library and references to do the encryption? Any sample or tutorial that I could follow?

Thank you.

Comment: I think you need to search here for PKCS7; there are dozens of questions on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For general cryptografy I use [bouncycastle library](http://www.bouncycastle.org/specifications.html). I haven't used PKCS7, but there is example how to use it: [PKCS7 Signatures using Bouncy Castle](http://i-proving.com/space/Technologies/JCE/PKCS7+Signatures+using+Bouncy+Castle)